# Does gdb stops ALL THREADS immediately?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gdb

I have the very strange situation I cannot explain. In the code:

```
Env = Global.Queue2Ctrl.FIFO(100);//Wait for a msg for 100ms
if (Env == 0) continue; //Timeout
printf("i=%d %x\n",++i, (Env->Msg));
if (!Env->Msg)
  BreakP();
....
```

For the purpose of this issue: other thread each 100ms gets from the pool and fills the Env structure (including pointer to the Msg). Then it sends Env pointer via FIFO. 
This thread processes the Env and returns it to the pool.

Once in some hundreds of thousands of cycles I fall on breakpoint - well, I understand that it may be if I have some bug, which I am looking for. 
What cannot be IMHO, that when I look in gdb (without stepping!) on the Env-Msg variable IT IS NOT ZERO!!!! Printf prints zero, I enter the if clause, but gdb shows "normal" value.
I can reproduce the situation once in 5-7 min and always gdb shows the good value? 
If this is racing condition, how this can be EXACTLY in one assembler command, when both threads are based on timeouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does gdb stops ALL THREADS immediately

No. On Linux, once one thread receives a `SIGTRAP` (due to breakpoint firing), GDB must stop all other threads (by iterating over the list of threads GDB knows about, and sending `SIGSTOP` to each).

If `Env` is shared between two threads, it is quite possible for `Env->Msg` to be `NULL` when `if` condition is evaluated, but to become non-`NULL` by the time GDB gives you prompt.

Comment: Great!!!
Exactly what I was looking for!!!
I suspected this, but the gdb documentation states the immediate stopping of all threads so determinately, that I was puzzled.

Many thanks!!!
Большое спасибо!!!